# Unable to get list in JSON from JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, server-side-rendering

I am having this problem where it keeps saying `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` when I am pretty sure this is right.

My response from the page the system is getting text from is here:

```
"[{\u0027message\u0027: \u0027amazing\u0027, \u0027sent_by\u0027: \u0027Tester Wupx\u0027}, {\u0027message\u0027: \u0027wow\u0027, \u0027sent_by\u0027: \u0027Tester Wupx\u0027}, {\u0027message\u0027: \u0027name\u0027, \u0027sent_by\u0027: \u0027guest\u0027}]"
```

Here is my code:

```js
async function getNewMessages() {
  await fetch(`/get_new_messages/s/${sId}`).then(async function(response) {
    const body = await response.text();
    arr = body.replace('[', "{'auto': [").replace(']', ']}')
    console.log(arr)
    json = await JSON.parse(arr);
    
    document.querySelector('.channel-messages ul').innerHTML = null;

    for (const i in Object.keys(json)) {
      const obj = json["auto"][i];
      document.querySelector('.channel-messages ul').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li style="padding-left: 10px; color: white; width: 100%;" onmouseover="const collection = this.children; this.style.background = '#535357'; this.style.color = 'white';" onmouseout="const collection = this.children; this.style.background = 'transparent'; this.style.color = 'white';"><b><img src="/assets/images/Goobler-meowsicles.png" width=40/> <onclickFunc onclick="">${obj["sent_by"]}</onclickFunc> <span class="badge" style="background: mediumpurple;">TESTER <i class="fa fa-check"></i></span> </b> <br>${obj["message"]}</li>`);
      console.log(obj)
      
    }
    
    /*document.querySelector('.channel-messages ul').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li style="padding-left: 10px; color: white; width: 100%;" onmouseover="const collection = this.children; this.style.background = '#535357'; this.style.color = 'white';" onmouseout="const collection = this.children; this.style.background = 'transparent'; this.style.color = 'white';"><b><img src="/assets/images/Goobler-meowsicles.png" width=40/> <onclickFunc onclick="">${json.message}</onclickFunc> <span class="badge" style="background: mediumpurple;">TESTER <i class="fa fa-check"></i></span> </b> <br>${json["messages"]['message']}</li>`);*/
  })
  //location.reload()
} /*edited code*/
```

I appreciate answers!

Comment: Have you tried ```JSON.parse(JSON.parse(arr)[0]);```?

Comment: Please edit your code to use temporary variables like `const auto = json['auto'];` and `const message = auto[i]["message"]`.  Log each intermediate variable and tell us what the output of the logs is (in fact you'll probably figure it out if you just break them up into variables and log each piece).

Comment: @anonsaicoder9 yes it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself, I will explain what I did.
I changed `await response.text()` to `await response.json()` instead.
I edited the for loop
Here is my code now:

```js
async function getNewMessages() {
  await fetch(`/get_new_messages/s/${sId}`).then(async function(response) {
    const body = await response.json();
    const jsonText = body.replaceAll('\u0027', '\u0022');
    const item = await JSON.parse(jsonText)/*.replaceAll(`'`, `"`);*/
    console.log("Edited array: "+jsonText);
    console.log("Raw array: "+body);
    console.log("Parsed array"+item)
    
    document.querySelector('.channel-messages ul').innerHTML = null;

    for (const obj of Object.entries(item.messages)) {
      const message = obj[1].message
      const sent_by = obj[1].sent_by
      document.querySelector('.channel-messages ul').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li style="padding-left: 10px; color: white; width: 100%;" onmouseover="const collection = this.children; this.style.background = '#535357'; this.style.color = 'white';" onmouseout="const collection = this.children; this.style.background = 'transparent'; this.style.color = 'white';"><b><img src="/assets/images/Goobler-meowsicles.png" width=40/> <onclickFunc onclick="">${sent_by}</onclickFunc> <span class="badge" style="background: mediumpurple;">TESTER <i class="fa fa-check"></i></span> </b> <br>${message}</li>`);
      console.log(obj[1])
    }
    
    /*document.querySelector('.channel-messages ul').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li style="padding-left: 10px; color: white; width: 100%;" onmouseover="const collection = this.children; this.style.background = '#535357'; this.style.color = 'white';" onmouseout="const collection = this.children; this.style.background = 'transparent'; this.style.color = 'white';"><b><img src="/assets/images/Goobler-meowsicles.png" width=40/> <onclickFunc onclick="">${json.message}</onclickFunc> <span class="badge" style="background: mediumpurple;">TESTER <i class="fa fa-check"></i></span> </b> <br>${json["messages"]['message']}</li>`);*/
  })
  //location.reload()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `\u0027` with `\u0022` i.e. single quotes with double quotes as the single quote is not a valid JSON.

**Updated**

```
const body = await response.text();
const jsonText = body.replaceAll('\u0027', '\u0022');
const item = await JSON.parse(jsonText);

for (const obj of item.messages) {
  document.querySelector('.channel-messages ul').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li style="padding-left: 10px; color: white; width: 100%;" onmouseover="const collection = this.children; this.style.background = '#535357'; this.style.color = 'white';" onmouseout="const collection = this.children; this.style.background = 'transparent'; this.style.color = 'white';"><b><img src="/assets/images/Goobler-meowsicles.png" width=40/> <onclickFunc onclick="">${obj.sent_by}</onclickFunc> <span class="badge" style="background: mediumpurple;">TESTER <i class="fa fa-check"></i></span> </b> <br>${obj.message}</li>`);
}
```

Comment: Your answer prints every character of the JSON file but I want every object, please try checking your answer again for any typos or errors in code. It also returns undefined when getting the `sent_by` object.

Comment: I did not get you. However, if you want each object then you can use `obj` and you can also access other fields like `obj.message`. If sent_by is missing in an object, it will return undefined. you can filter it out by `if (obj.sent_by)`. The idea is you can replace `for` body with your own logic'

Comment: When I log `sent_by` as you did in the answer, for some reason returns undefined, please review my code at pastebin https://pastebin.com/jJKWdqpi for anything I am missing

Comment: Code looks fine. Can you share the output of `console.log("Raw array: "+body);`?

Comment: Raw array: "{\u0027messages\u0027: [{\u0027message\u0027: \u0027amazing\u0027, \u0027sent_by\u0027: \u0027Tester Wupx\u0027}, {\u0027message\u0027: \u0027wow\u0027, \u0027sent_by\u0027: \u0027Tester Wupx\u0027}, {\u0027message\u0027: \u0027name\u0027, \u0027sent_by\u0027: \u0027guest\u0027}]}"

Comment: I can share a video of what happens when I enter `getNewMessages()` if you like

Comment: Updated the answer based on the response. This should work just fine now

Comment: its giving me the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: arr.messages is not iterable`

Comment: Please share a video. It seems the http response is changing intermittently. Also. check at your end that the HTTP response is not changing every time.

Comment: https://img.guildedcdn.com/ContentMediaGenericFiles/ab42ea9d94a23f7b41f946b526408b75-Full.mp4?w=1365&h=767 video

Comment: The output seems fine. Can you share the `getNewMessages()` code?

Comment: that is the code I sent in the question https://pastebin.com/jJKWdqpi

Comment: try this https://pastebin.com/1J8VHaGR. Also, please pay attention to the already updated code above

Answer (score 0):

If your `body` equals to this:

```
"[{\u0027message\u0027: \u0027amazing\u0027, \u0027sent_by\u0027: \u0027Tester Wupx\u0027}, {\u0027message\u0027: \u0027wow\u0027, \u0027sent_by\u0027: \u0027Tester Wupx\u0027}, {\u0027message\u0027: \u0027name\u0027, \u0027sent_by\u0027: \u0027guest\u0027}]"
```

Then try in this way:

```
    const body = await response.text();
    // arr = body.replace('[', "{'auto': [").replace(']', ']}') <= remove this line
    json = await JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(json)
```